Microsoft Blazor QuickGrid problem with scrolling
After a while I had switched to Blazor on .NET 8, I noticed that the QuickGrid stopped working. The symptom is that it is flickering/jittering while scrolling and stay in that mode indefinitely. When tracing, I can see Skip grows from 0 while I'm gradually scrolling grid down and suddenly it gets back to Skip=0, Take=say 30. That marks it is broken, it gets jittering even without touching a scroll bar. What can be the reason for this?
Additionally:

It worked Ok on .NET 6 for sure
It uses virtualization
It uses ItemsProvider for remote data access

Thanks

Post the QuickGrid version, amd specify the versions and setup for the rest of the app as well. Ideal would be a [mre].

My apologies, More detail are as following: the QuickGrid verion is 8.0.1, the app is the Blazor WASM 8.0.1

Restrict the size of the html container the grid is in! Sounds like the virtualization component is confused calculating it position. I have seen this before.


Restrict the size of the html container. Yes, everything is hardcoded including container height and row height, no effect. Thoughts?


Per the docs,

"Enabling virtualization is just a matter of passing
Virtualize="true", but for it to work properly and reliably, you must
ensure that every row renders with the same known height. For example,
you must ensure that text does not wrap and cause variations in row
height. If rows do vary in height, scrolling will behave erratically."

Can you test your grid with data that has text/values which are very small/concise (maybe only single letters) to see if this resolves flickering?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add details, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.
